# Multiple XHR calls in window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, ajax

If I have a single XHR (in my case, the form of an AngularJS `$http`) in a `window.onbeforeunload` function, eg saving unsaved work to the server before tab close, it seems to fire OK (at least from my testing in latter day Chrome and Firefox).

But if I have many XHRs initiated in a while/for loop (not chained asyncronously), only the first XHR fires most of the time and sometimes two or more... with increasing rarity. What's weird is logs before and after ALL the XHR send code are printed to the console.

It's like the browser is prepared to run all the code, but not actually carry out all the actions (complete the XHRs).

Is there any way to ensure all XHRs are sent successfully in `onbeforeunload`?  And even if I batched all the calls up into one, is there any guarantee that that one would send? Or are my observations just some race condition fluke?

Comment: Afaik you can't perform any async operation in onbeforeunload handler with success, the page is closed (via onunload handler, if defined) when the execution moves out of the handler, and all async operations are aborted.

Comment: @Teemu, so you're saying I'm just lucky to keep getting >= one XHR being sent in all my tests.

Comment: More or less that's the case. Digging something official ...

Comment: Can't you make one and have the server make all the calls?

Comment: @epascarello the thought occurred to me, and I already edited the question to that effect. If I can't guarantee that I'll have at least one XHR, it's back to the drawing board

Comment: ANd sometimes you can't guarantee  the one either.

Comment: OK, well, that's the answer then. I'm not sure why vendors don't support this better. Auto-saving unsaved data is surely a common use case.

Comment: Well, it's a long story, but [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#unloading-documents) says: "_For each EventSource object eventSource whose relevant global object is equal to window, [forcibly close eventSource](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#concept-eventsource-forcibly-close)._" An XMLHttpRequest is an event source, hence it is closed.

Comment: @Teemu outstanding research. :) Thanks for your efforts guys!  How come everyone writes comments instead of answers these days? Well, I'll upvote your comment instead I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using asynchronous XHR you could probably use [keepalive fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-keepalive-flag) or [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) for that purpose.